# My code is not drawing bars to the screen from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I am trying to make one of those sorting algorithms and want to have the bars get randomly generated with height and x position. However, when I run the code, it doesn't draw any bars. I'm also not getting any errors sent so I have no idea what's going wrong.

```js
class Bar {
  constructor(x, height) {
    this.height = height;
    this.size = 10;
    this.x = x;
  }

  draw() {
    fill("blue");
    rect(this.x * this.size, height - (this.height * this.size), this.size, this.height * this.size);
  }
}

let bars = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  generateBars();
}

function generateBars() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 39; i++) {
    randomX = random(0, 39);
    randomHeight = random(0, 40)
    for (let j = 0; j < bars.length; j++) {
      if (bars[j].x == randomX) {
        randomX = random(0, 39);
      } else {
        for (let h = 0; h < bars.length; h++) {
          if (bars[j].height == randomHeight) {
            randomHeight = random(0, 40);
          } else {
            bars[i] = new Bar(randomX, randomHeight);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  for (let k = 0; k < bars.length; k++) {
    bars[k].draw();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In your draw function you use a variable height that doesn’t seem to exist.

Comment: @James height is a variable in p5.js that is the height of the canvas. i tried switching it to 400 and still nothing. it also works with singular bars

Answer (score 1):

The logic in `generateBars` seems convoluted and the intention is unclear.

As far as I see `Bar`'s `x` property acts more of a `value` property storing the number to be sorted later because it is multiplied by `size` in `draw()`. (e.g. `x` is not the final `x` position the bar should be rendered at, as it's name implies).

I would simply intanstiate `Bar` like so:

```js
class Bar{
  constructor(x, height){
    this.height = height;
    this.size = 10;
    this.x = x;
  }
  
  draw(){
    fill("blue");
    rect(this.x * this.size, height - (this.height * this.size), this.size, this.height * this.size);
  }
}

let bars = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  generateBars();
}

function generateBars(){
  for(let i = 0; i < 40; i++){
    randomHeight = random(0, 40)
    bars[i] = new Bar(i, randomHeight);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  for(let k = 0; k < bars.length; k++){
    bars[k].draw();
  }
}

function mouseClicked(){
  setup();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

(I've added a hacky `mouseClicked()` handler so it's easy to regenerate the bars for testing/debugging purposes. You may not need it in your final code)

**Update** Based on your comment, it's the bar height that is tightly coupled to the value to be sorted later.

One idea is to simply pre-generate the list of numbers to sort and [`shuffle()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/shuffle) them first:

```js
class Bar{
  constructor(x, height){
    this.height = height;
    this.size = 10;
    this.x = x;
  }
  
  draw(){
    fill("blue");
    rect(this.x * this.size, height - (this.height * this.size), this.size, this.height * this.size);
  }
}

let bars = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  generateBars();
}

function generateBars(){
  // array to be sorted
  let barValues = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < 40; i++){
    // values are sorted first
    barValues[i] = i;
  }
  // then we shuffle them: second argument = shuffle in place (replacing the old array)
  shuffle(barValues, true);
  // assign shuffled values to Bar instances
  for(let i = 0; i < 40; i++){
    bars[i] = new Bar(i, barValues[i]);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  for(let k = 0; k < bars.length; k++){
    bars[k].draw();
  }
}

function mouseClicked(){
  setup();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i want the code generating bars to make sure no two bars are in the same position or have the same height

Comment: I see. Your question should have clarified this. So it's not x that stores the value to be sorted later but height ? If so, you can start with a sorted array (which guarantees you won't bars with the same height), then shuffle the array). See the update above.

Comment: @MaddoxFox Thats nowhere in your question. George Profenza build a very nice proto type for you. Why not modify it yourself ?